# How to limit columns in a table in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tabular

Here is my code to print the product of a number from 500 to that number:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
table = []
if num > 0:
    for i in range(1,500):
        prod = num * i
        if prod >= 500:
            break
        table.append(prod)
k = len(table)
j = 0
while j < len(table):
    print(table[k-1],end=" ")
    k = k - 1
    j = j + 1
```

this is the output:

```
Enter a number: 40
480 440 400 360 320 280 240 200 160 120 80 40
```

Now,As you can see,These numbers are printed continuously in one line. Is there any way that the output could be in form of a table with maximum **six columns?**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> table = [480, 440, 400, 360, 320, 280, 240, 200, 160, 120, 80, 40, 520]
>>> for i in range((len(table)//6)+1):
...    print(*table[i*6:(i+1)*6])
...    if len(table)%6 != 0 and len(table)//6 == i:
...       print(*table[(i+1)*6:])
... 
480 440 400 360 320 280
240 200 160 120 80 40
520
```

**EDIT:**

You want a reversed list which it is limited to six columns, so try this:

```
table.reverse() # it revreses the list
size = 6        # it's the size of limitation

# it splits the list into 2D list with limitation of "size"
limited_table = [table[i:i+size] for i  in range(0, len(table), size)]

for x in limited_table:
    print(*x)
```

Comment: What if `table` size is not multiple of 6?

Comment: @Syed Zubair Bokhari how do you want your output? it works!

Comment: @SyedZubairBokhari  You're welcome. Please mark this as true answer

Answer (score 0):

`tab[::-1]` returns the reversed list.

```
for i, val in enumerate(tab[::-1]):
    print(val, end=' ')
    if i and not i % 6:
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your `for` to this:

```
for index,i in enumerate(range(num ,500, num)):
    if index % 6 ==0:
        table.append([])
    table[-1].append(i)
```

Output will be a 2d list like this:

```
[[40, 80, 120, 160, 200, 240], [280, 320, 360, 400, 440, 480]]
```

and for printing:

```
print(*table, sep='\n')
```